# Replace value in a list of a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Assume there is one DataFrame as following

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'store':range(1,4),
                   'food':[['fish', 'apple'],
                           ['orange', 'water'],
                           ['egg', 'fish']]})  
df

store   food
    1   [fish, apple]
    2   [orange, water]
    3   [egg, fish]
```

I would like to replace 'fish' with 'milk' in all df. So the new DataFrame should be like below

```
    store   food
    1   [milk, apple]
    2   [orange, water]
    3   [egg, milk]
```

I have tried "for-loop" to do that but it seems to be wrong

```
food1 = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    for j in range(len(df['food'][0])):
        if df['food'][i][j] == 'fish':
            food1.append('milk')
        else:
            food1.append(df['food'][i][j])
food1
['milk', 'apple', 'orange', 'water', 'egg', 'milk']
```

any suggestions how to do this? many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one-liner that does it all:

```
df["food"] = df["food"].map(lambda x: list(map(lambda x: x.replace('fish', 'milk'), x)))
```

EDIT: removed useless code